# Where can I get information on US congress and government?

Tags: visualization

I want to make a website that displays information about the United States Congress and make it easy to understand. As far as I know the US congress has everything recorded and under the public domain including votes, etc. Is there some way to access that automatically without making FOIA requests? I basically am imagining a system where you have a UI of the full seats of congress and you can hover/highlight on live streams of representatives, save information you are interested in, query information, etc. I just am not sure where to get the data at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go through these resources maybe you'll get the data of your interest at any of these--

- [GovTrack.us Open Data & API](https://www.govtrack.us/developers)
- [Resources A to Z - Congress.gov Resources](https://www.congress.gov/resources/display/content/Resources+A+to+Z)
- [Open Data](https://www.data.gov/)
- [Data and Statistics about the United States](https://www.usa.gov/statistics)

Hope it helps. But in case you need more data and info update me on that. I'll try my best to bring you more data. Cheers!

**Update**

API for Campaign Contributions- [Open API](https://api.open.fec.gov/developers/)

Comment: Glad, I could help! Cheers! :)

Comment: Is there an api somewhere of campaign contributions?

Comment: Try this open API, maybe it will add up something.  https://api.open.fec.gov/developers/